# Failed to redirect route in NetxJs on AWS EC2 server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am running NextJs app over AWS EC2 serve> want to redirect routes having trailing slashes to non trailing slash routes.For Ex - `/industry-reports/` should route to `/industry-reports`.For that I am using custom server routing  inside `server.js` file.BUt locally its working fine but on server its failing and showing below error:

```
Cannot GET /industry-reports/
```

**server.js**

```
   server.get('/industry-reports', async (req, res) => {

    if (req.url.substring(req.url.length - 1) === '/') {
    req.url = req.url.substring(0, req.url.length - 1);
    return res.redirect(301, process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION' ? `https://www.google.com` : `https://facebook.com`)
  }

  const actualPage = '/industry-reports'
  app.render(req, res, actualPage)
});
```

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

> /industry-reports/ should route to /industry-reports

The default behavior of NextJS is already what you are trying to do. You don't need custom routing to handle trailing slashes. It will work if you simply delete the redirect code you've written.

> "By default Next.js will redirect urls with trailing slashes to their counterpart without a trailing slash."

From: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash